# MonoTouch: Could not load 'monotouch' for registration

Tags: ios, crash, xamarin.ios

I am getting the following crash reports from some recent apps deployed to the app store. I am not sure what is causing it or how to fix it.

> Could not load 'monotouch' for registration. This could be due to an
>   outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/1BEDC27F-B313-4240-8490-EAD680F8E78A/PhotoTour.app/monotouch.dll

It refers to the Simulator in the error, but the app from the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message itself refers to a condition that *was* known to exists only in the simulator. The iOS Simulator does not remove old files (it only updates them).

In recent MonoTouch versions there's another fix now that should prevent even this message to occur (on simulator builds). It's very unlikely that the *same* condition (stale binaries) is occuring on devices.

The exception behind the error means that that the types inside the assembly (monotouch.dll) could not be registered properly. This should not happen, even less randomly (i.e. **if** it occurs it should be systematically on every execution and on every device, including when testing). Since registration occurs everytime at startup it's hard to see why testing (and Apple app approval) has not catched this.

Please fill a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) report including the exact version of MonoTouch being used and attach a log of the (release) build (add `-v -v -v` so we'll get more details about the build). Also attach the logs from where you gathered the above message - other lines of the same logs might gives us some clues.

Comment: I would be happy to send you a free Promo code so that you can install it from the App store, run it and see the dump. my email is ianvink[AT]gmail.com. It is happening to 3 apps in the store, all new apps.

Comment: I noticed they all had `--noregistrar` in the build agruments, that was due to a bug a long time ago, could that be affecting it?

Comment: That's very likely. That option changes the registration to a totally different code path. One that is less used (since it's not the default option) so it could be why we have not heard about this before today.

Comment: It was put in to fix a problem ages ago, I am removing it now and resubmitting the apps to the app store.